# where is DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in gentoo?

Tags: ssh, dbus, gentoo

I have a code that connects to dbus via ssh and works in ubuntu, but I have to migrate to gentoo. 
In ubuntu I wrote a script that finds the pid of dbus that has DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in its environments and I source export it, so I can ssh and also having access to dbus of target. 
I used exactly the same script in gentoo, but it didn't find the dbus session.
Is here anyone who are familiar with gentoo and dbus in it and could help me? I want to ssh and then have access to dbus in gentoo.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though dbus sessions are normally only started together with X sessions on Gentoo. I could only find instances of that variable in these files...

- /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/80-dbus
- /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc

Having said that, I ssh'd to a Ubuntu server box and the variable wasn't set there either. Maybe it's only normally set in the desktop version or maybe it requires some package to be installed.

If you're not trying to connect to an existing dbus session, I guess what you'd need to do is launch a new one as part of you ssh login with .bash_profile or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have X session started and want to get DBUS address of that session, it's in the `_DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` property of the window owning `_DBUS_SESSION_BUS_SELECTION_[hostname]_[machineid]` selection. Not sure if there is an easy way to extract it with shell one-liner/xlsatoms/xprop combination. I have node.js [script](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/lib/address-x11.js) which gives you address using [node-x11](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11) library